# Javascript `await` "SyntaxError: Unexpted identifier" even if I am awaiting inside an `async` function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

Javascript `await` gives the following error when I do await inside an `async` module

```
let ImagesArray = await getImages();
                            ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\junai\Desktop\giantbomb-api-test\index.js:8:17)
```

Here is my code snippet. What am I doing wrong?

```
    async function getImages(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            request.get("URL", function (error, response, body) {
                let images = JSON.parse(body).results.map((image)=>{
                    return image.original_url;
                })
                resolve(images);
        });
      })
    }


    module.exports = async function addGame(req, res){
      let ImagesArray = await getImages();
      ImagesArray.forEach(URL => {
          images.push({
              "data": URL,
              "uploadType" : "url",
              "type": "image/jpeg",
              "name": game.name
          })
      });
      console.log(images);
    }
```

On the other hand the following code works but the output is different:

```
var images = [{
    "image": {
        "data": "FIRST IMAGE",
        "uploadType": "url",
        "type": "image/jpeg",
        "name": game.name
    }
}];
(async function main() {
    let ImagesArray = await getImages();
    ImagesArray.forEach(URL => {
        images.push({
            "data": URL,
            "uploadType": "url",
            "type": "image/jpeg",
            "name": game.name
        })
    });
    console.log(images); // [{"image" : {"data": "FIRST IMAGE", "uploadType" : "url", "type": "image/jpeg", "name": game.name } }, {...}, {...} ]
})();
console.log(images); // [{"image" : {"data": "FIRST IMAGE", "uploadType" : "url", "type": "image/jpeg", "name": game.name } }]
```

Comment: Run your snippet, and it gives a ReferenceError (runtime), not a SyntaxError - the syntax looks fine. (Maybe your environment doesn't support `await` as-is, and you need to change configuration or upgrade?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's tagged `node.js`, it's presumably not intended to be run in a browser. And the traceback indicates that the error is happening when importing the file, not when trying to run the functions.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If I run that function inside an async IIFE `(async function() {})();` then it gives no error but I need the await results in a variable and IIFE limits the scope.

Comment: What version of node.js are you running this in?

Comment: @Bergi It's v8.9.4

Comment: Where does `images` array come from in the first snippet? I have a feeling this has to do with context..meaning, the issue isn't necessarily with your code snippets but how you're using them.

Comment: @MattOestreich The `images` array is defined in a higher scope then the `getImages()` function

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue at all... Is this repo publicly available? There is something else going on here besides async/await that is causing this.. [This is the code I used](https://gist.github.com/oze4/698881cbd0141c66fc7817eeb95dd1b7) to try and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the second snippet is that the `main` function is executed asynchronously. You print `images` before its execution is finished.

Since an `async` function returns a `Promise`,  you can use [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) like this:

```
var images = [{
    "image": {
        "data": "FIRST IMAGE",
        "uploadType": "url",
        "type": "image/jpeg",
        "name": game.name
    }
}];

async function main() {
   let ImagesArray = await getImages();
   ImagesArray.forEach(URL => {
       images.push({
           "data": URL,
           "uploadType": "url",
           "type": "image/jpeg",
           "name": game.name
       })
    });
});

main().then(() => console.log(images));
```

Once the [top-level `await` proposal lands](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), you will be able to just await `main`.

Comment: But I want to `await` the result so that I can save it inside a variable. How can I wait for the response before proceeding further? I don't want to move the rest of the code inside the `then` function

Comment: Your second example logs different `images` due to scope.

Comment: @JunaidAnwar Thanks for the edit suggestion. Actually, since the `main` function in this case is mutating `images`, it does not need to return anything. I edited my answer accordingly. Regarding your question, it depends on how `addGame` (`main`) function is used. Do you have more code available?